# Backup local svn repository to Google Drive

Tags: svn, repository, backup, google-drive-api

I have been using Tortoise SVN and VisualSVNManager to create local svn repositories for my projects. Is there a way to back up those repositories to Google Drive? I know that you can use

```
svnadmin hotcopy path/to/repository path/to/backup --clean-logs
```

to back up locally.  Could I use this to back up to Google Drive? What would the path to Google Drive be?

Thanks!

Comment: `svndump` is better suited for backups. However are you sure you want to publish your code to the whole world (google drive)? Why not just use a removable usb disk or something, so that you stay in control of your data. If you really need to use some cloud service, then take a look at owncloud instead.

Comment: Isn't Google drive private?

Comment: Data on google private? You _have_ heard about what came out over the last month? About the NSA checking each and every bit it can get hold of? Because they officially claim it "legal"? And then handing the data on to interested companies? So no, that data certainly is _not_ private.

Comment: Would it be better then to backup in an external drive?

Comment: I'd say so, that is what I suggested in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup to external drive since Google drive is not very safe. Thanks to arkascha!